Rigging Mesh With Separate Parts Deforms Incorrectly download model

Character downloaded from cgtraders in .fbx format.
First it Separated by Loose Parts (P in Edit Mode) and then group in Object Mode Ctrl + P with keep transform.
Then add bone using rigify basic bones, link control rig with mesh using weight paint.
Finally object cracks or deform unintentionally in pose mode.
Am I doing some thing wrong?
Also when joined using Ctrl + J weight paint is not linking bone with mesh. So both options failed.
[[
